# Difference between two images but in certain region only

Tags: python, opencv

I have two images, where i need to find the difference. i can easily did with the help of SSIM function. Now i want to find the difference between two images but only selected region (i want to ignore some region , which i marked as a rectangular). [image]

Comment: You can use masking. What library/tool are you using?

Comment: i am using Opencv python  in spyder.  . what masking you are talking about ?

Comment: I dont know opencv but in Numpy you can use a mask (matrix which consists of True/False elements) to mask certain values to the operation you want to perform. I think it is better if you join a code of what you tried.